# SPFx - Ask individual consent to use Graph API

Tags: spfx, microsoft-graph

On a webpart I would like to show the current user calendar events, but I don't want to ask for an Admin to approve the API permission for everyone first.

Is there a way to, when a new user hit the page, ask permission to access that specific user calendar?

Comment: You need to use **Delegated permission**. Let me know if [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts) helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SPFX web part then you don't need to ask for any consent because by default SPFX web part run using current user's context.

You can use graph API directly in SPFX Web part with current user.

You can go through below guideline which shows how to use Graph API in SPFX web part.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial

Hope it will helpful to you.